# Which PCL 6/PCL XL driver?

Tags: linux, drivers, printer, cups

I'm trying to setup a print server via CUPS. I've been told that a generic PCL6/PCL XL driver will work fine, but in CUPS there are a million versions listed:

- Generic PCL 6/PCL XL LF Printer - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9 (en)
- Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5c (en)
- Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic/lj5gray (en)

etc.

How do I know which one to choose?